# Replacing unusual values in timeseries data with moving average values

Tags: r, lubridate

I would like to replace unusual rainfall with reasonable values.

I wish to use moving average of 2-3 week's of rainfall to replace them.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

week <- c("10-03-2021", "10-10-2021", "10-17-2021", "10-24-2021", "10-31-2021", "11-6-2021", "11-13-2021", "11-20-2021", "11-27-2021")
rainfall <- c(11, 12, 13, 1010, 1000, 16, 16, 18, 15)

tbl <- tibble(week = mdy(week), 
              rainfall = rainfall)
```

Comment: To provide a sensible answer you need to define the range of expected weekly rainfall or at a minimum the maximum expected weekly rainfall.

Comment: Are you sure that weeks with unusually high rainfall are to be removed? To be away from the average is not a good criterion to see those data as possible outliers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am assuming that the rainfall would lie between 11 and 18. Can we please fill it using moving average of 3 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` in combination with the `zoo` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
tbl <- tbl %>% mutate(rainfall.MA = rollmean(rainfall, 3, fill = NA, align = 'right'))
```

If you only wish to replace the high values (say, 1000 or more):

```
highvalues <- which(tbl$rainfall >= 1000 )
tbl$rainfall[ highvalues ] <- tbl$rainfall.MA[ highvalues ]
```

If your aim is to deal with outliers, you might look into logaritmic transformation, such as

```
tbl$ln_rainfall <- log(tbl$rainfall)
```

Comment: `rollmean(rainfall, 3, fill = NA, align = 'right')` can be written compactly as `rollmeanr(rainfall, 3, fill = NA)` with an `r` on the end.